# Update Combobox Selection Based on File

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I (unfortunately) need to set a ComboBox selection based on the existence of a file.

```
-(NSString *)defaultSet{

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Setdefault"]];
}
```

Files would only be

```
 .1, .2, .3, .4 or .5
```

and the values are already set in the ComboBox.

Figured it out..

```
if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:@"/usr/local/.1"]) [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"defaultSet"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Needed to use setObject not setValue. Such as below.

```
if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:@"/usr/local/.5"]) [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"5" forKey:@"setDefault"];
```